# Rocket Chat docker-compose.yml not validating

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, rocket.chat

I'm setting up rocket chat in AWS using the doc's provided by the rocket chat folks. Here's the file I've copied (from [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/paas-deployments/aws/#configure-dns-w-aws-route-53)):

```
 version: '2'

 services:
 rocketchat:
     image: rocket.chat:latest
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
     - ./uploads:/app/uploads
     environment:
     - PORT=3000
     - ROOT_URL=https://<ABC.DOMAIN.COM>
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
     - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
     - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=True
     depends_on:
     - mongo
     ports:
     - 3000:3000

 mongo:
     image: mongo:4.0
     restart: unless-stopped
     command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0 --storageEngine=mmapv1
     volumes:
     - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
     - ./data/dump:/dump

 # this container's job is just to run the command to initialize the replica set.
 # it will run the command and remove himself (it will not stay running)
 mongo-init-replica:
     image: mongo:4.0
     command: >
     bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
         mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval \"
             rs.initiate({
             _id: 'rs0',
             members: [ { _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' } ]})\" &&
         s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
         echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
         sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     depends_on:
     - mongo
```

When I try running `docker-compose up -d` I'm getting parsing errors I can't figure out (not familiar with yaml):

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 33, column 5
could not find expected ':'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 37, column 16
```

It looks like its having a hard time parsing the multiline bash script, but I can't figure out why. The syntax seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two lines are the problem:

```
command: >
bash -c
```

Since `bash -c` is at the same indentation level as `command:`, the flow scalar started with `>` ends there (making it an empty string). YAML now expects another key since this indentation level contains a map. A key ends with `:`, but the line does not contain one, hence the error (it does find a `:`, but on another line which is too late).

What you actually want to do is to make `bash -c` part of the flow scalar. You do this by indenting it more than the previous line:

```
command: >
  bash -c
    # snip
```